# Converting .png movie in .avi to .wmv with MEncoder

Tags: wmv, mencoder

I saved a number of .png files generated from rotation of a pretty figure that I made using Octave.  I converted them into a .png .avi movie using MEncoder, which looks exactly like I want on my Linux machine.  Now, though, I'd like to embed it into a PowerPoint for an upcoming conference...and there is the problem.

I converted my .png files using:

```
mencoder mf://*.png -mf w=640:h=480:fps=10:type=png -ovc copy -oac copy - o moviehyppara.avi
```

Now...I assumed I could do something like

```
mencoder moviehyppara.avi -o moviehyppara.wmv -ovc lavc -lavcopts -ofps vcodec=wmv2
```

and many other versions, but found myself immediately in over my head.  So far, no luck with Google or man pages, although there is much to go through still.  The video produced is only one frame of the original.  All the while I am noticing that almost every reply to a forum post asking similar questions suggests ditching MEncoder for FFMpeg.  I considered giving up, since I'll probably get to the conference and discover I should have done it with wmv1, but it's become personal.  Advice?

Comment: Well..  Gave in and did it with FFMpeg after all.  Windows seems happy, for now.  Anyone else with my problem, ffmpeg -i moviehyppara.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 WinMovie.avi worked, albeit with many errors about frame size changes that didn't much matter for me.  The question of how to do it with MEncoder still remains...

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the original PNGs?  Why not just encode directly to wmv2?

```
mencoder "mf://*.png" -mf fps=10 -o moviehyppara.wmv -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=wmv2
```

Incidentally, I am using Octave and mencoder to do just that.